# Calculating transpose of a tensor in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I am required to calculate the following in Paraview:

[image]

How can I calculate the transpose used in the above formula ?  Basically I would like to know how to calculate the transpose of a matrix in Paraview.

Comment: Can you write this with simple arithmetic ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal I am sorry. I didn't get you. In the above formula, in the the u before the minus. I am just calculating the gradient of u. And in the u after the minus, I am first calculating the gradient of u and then taking the transpose. BTW u is a second order tensor. By simple arithmetic did you expect such an explanation?

Comment: nope, by simple arithmetics I mean to use operations supported by python by default.
What is delta_u ? what is delta_u_T ?

Comment: Using numpy the following would be the formula:
omega = 1\2*(gradient.(u)-gradient.(transpose.(u)))

Comment: numpy is supported ParaView : https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_calculator_and_programmable_filter

Comment: @MathieuWestphal After a long discussion with the OP, we have figured out that the code provided in **EDIT 2** of the answer I have posted helps the OP achieve his goal. Considering that you have no doubt much more experience and knowledge with ParaView, would you mind checking that the snippet is OK and confirming that this is what should be done? Thank you.

Comment: It looks good to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Nico Vuaille, you should make use of Numpy support in ParaView. Simply apply a Programmable Filter to the dataset of interest, and supply a script comparable to the following.

```
import numpy as np
u = inputs[0].PointData['Velocity']
# Calculate gradient here, say uGrad
output.PointData.append(uGrad, 'Gradient')
```

**EDIT**: I have actually tried to generate your calculation with one of my datasets and realised that my answer and comments are not so helpful. Therefore, this is what I would suggest now, which should work:

- Load your dataset in ParaView
- Apply a Gradient / Gradient Of Unstructured Dataset filter on your dataset and select the velocity field as the input field (I used [Gradient Of Unstructured Dataset](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/List_of_filters#Gradient_Of_Unstructured_DataSet), from which you have the possibility to also directly work out both divergence and vorticity fields).
- Apply a Programmable Filter filter to the resulting dataset you obtained from the previous step and supply the code below.

Script

```
import numpy as np
grad = inputs[0].PointData['Gradients']
omega = (grad - np.transpose(grad, axes=(0, 2, 1))) / 2
output.PointData.append(omega, 'Omega')
```

You should end up with another item in your ParaView pipeline that only contains the expected Omega.

**EDIT 2**: The input file is using the XMDF format. When loaded into ParaView, it is interpreted as a Multi-Block Dataset of Blocks. As a result, the code snippet provided to the Script argument of Programmable Filter has to be updated to:

```
import paraview.vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter as dsa
for i in range(inputs[0].GetNumberOfBlocks()):
    data = dsa.WrapDataObject(inputs[0].GetBlock(i))
    grad = data.PointData['Gradients']
    omega = (grad - np.transpose(grad, axes=(0, 2, 1))) / 2
    data.PointData.append(omega, 'Omega')
    output.SetBlock(i, data.VTKObject)
```

Comment: Here is `uGrad` used to compute the gradient and is the result of this computation stored under the name of the array 'Gradient'? Can you please suggest the source where I can find what function I should be  using for calculating the transpose?  Please correct me if I am wrong. For calculating gradient using numpy we should be using `np.gradient(Velocity)` right? But here I see `uGrad` has been used to calculate the gradient. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, uGrad is simply the variable name associated with the result of the gradient (through [numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html?highlight=gradient#numpy.gradient) I suppose?) and 'Gradient' is the name of the newly created ParaView field. You can directly calculate Omega, by having `omega = (uGrad + np.transpose(uGrad)) / 2` and return this as another PointData field (append `output.PointData.append(omega, 'Omega'` to the current snippet for example).

Comment: I applied the Programmable filter and used [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FZV6.jpg) code. I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ0ZF.jpg). Also I am not able to create any contours or slices. Can you please tell if there is anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you include `print(u.shape, omega.shape)` in the Script and provide the output?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQOxO.jpg) is the code snippet with `print(u.shape, omega.shape)`. I am not getting any out put apart from the same error message as in the previous comment.

Comment: You need to put the print statement before the output statement as the error is yielded by this latter. :)

Comment: My bad. But now with the corrected code, I am able to see the vtk blocks. But there is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKx6j.jpg) output message. Also, I am not able to create contour, but I am able to create slice, though the slice appears blank.

Comment: My bad all the way actually. Please see the EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Can you please tell briefly the function of `axes=(0, 2, 1)`. I followed the procedure suggested in the edit. I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1vUP.jpg) error.

Comment: What is the shape of the Gradient produced by ParaView? In my case, the it was (N, 3, 3),hence why the (0, 2, 1) in transpose.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I calculate the shape of the gradient produced by ParaView?

Comment: So, after the line `grad = inputs[0].PointData['Gradients']`, which gives you access to the Gradients array produced by the Gradient filter, you can simply add `print(grad.shape)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212666/discussion-between-giri-and-patol75).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be easily computed using `Python calculator` (no need for programmable filter):

- To compute the gradient, type:

```
gradient(u)
```

- To compute the symmetric part of the tensor `gradient(u)`:

```
strain(u)
```

- To compute the non-symmetric part, `Omega`, of the gradient tensor:

[image]

```
gradient(u) - strain(u)
```

Note that that the `gradient(u)` tensor can be written as follows:

[image]